# About all primes $p$ such that $s_p=1+\prod_{k\leq p,k\text{ prime}}k$ is prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Inspired by Euclid's proof that there are infinitely many prime numbers, I started looking at numbers of the form $$s_p=1+\prod_{k\leq p,k\text{ prime}}k$$
where $p$ is a prime number. I couldn't find any literature that tries to characterize the set of all prime numbers $p$ such that $s_p$ is prime as well. With some brute force computations, we see that if $p=2,3,5,7,11$ then $s_p$ is prime as well but $s_{13}$ is not. My question is, is the set
$$S=\{p\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 2}\text{ prime}:s_p\text{ prime}\}$$
infinite? Or finite? Can one prove anything about the cardinality of $S$? Does $S$ admit any (obvious) structures? I wouldn't have any idea on how to start, so I'd appreciate any suggestions/ideas/solutions!

Comment: See "primorial numbers"

Comment: This question is discussed in http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2002-71-237/S0025-5718-01-01315-1/S0025-5718-01-01315-1.pdf

Comment: RMG.. Do you mean if written as an answer, or just that it gives the right thing to search for?

Comment: The latter is what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer check gives values $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 31, 379, 1019, 1021,...$. Putting this into the Online Encyclopaedia of Integer Sequences gives [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A005234), and there are several links from that page with more information. In particular there is a [scan of a journal article from 1987](http://oeis.org/A006794/a006794.pdf) in which it is conjectured that there are infinitely many such numbers. I doubt this will be proved anytime soon; intuitively it feels significantly harder than the unsolved conjecture that there are infinitely many [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime), for example.